# Why my string replace is not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm trying to replace a placeholder in a string I'm generating.

My string looks like this:

```
 var s = 'module("SlapOS UI Basic Interaction"); ' +
         'asyncTest( "${base_url}", function() { ' +
         ' expect( __number__ ); ' +
         ' ok(testForElement("div#global-panel"), "element present");' +
         ' start(); })';
```

And I want to replace `__number__`.

I can get the index correctly like so:

```
 s.indexOf("__number__");
```

but replacing does not work...

```
 s.replace("__number__", "1");
```

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong here? Makes no sense to my why it does not work.

Comment: `s = s.replace("__number__", "1");`

Comment: Try RegExp `.replace(/__number__/, "1");`

Comment: Works for me. Hate to ask this, but maybe you're forgetting to assign the result of the replace to something?

Comment: both don't work. No problem in Firebug though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method does not modify the existing string. It returns a new one.

```
var result = s.replace("__number__", "1");
```

Comment: darn.... I think I always forget :-)